# Keep the cursor in the textarea and add each content per click

Tags: javascript, textarea

My js: http://jsfiddle.net/creepyzero/4jQ4x/

How do I keep the cursor in the textarea when I click test/test 2 ?

How do I add a and b each time I click test/test 2 ? a and b must be added in the same onclick.

Example:

- I click test, what the textarea has is 1
- Then I click test 2, what the textarea has is 13
- Then I click test, what the textarea has is 132
  Thank for your helps :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand both questions, this modification to your fiddle should more-or-less do what you are asking:

http://jsfiddle.net/trott/4jQ4x/25/

JS:

```
var testContents = ['1','2'];
var test2Contents = ['3','4']

function add(contentsArray) {
        var x = document.getElementById('test');
        var addValue = contentsArray.shift();
        if (typeof addValue !== "undefined") {
            x.value += addValue;
        }


        x.focus();    
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea name="note" id="test"></textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="add(testContents);">Test</a>
<a href="#" onclick="add(test2Contents);">Test 2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what im talking about, but your code only works one time :(

Answer (score 1):

Cannot understand your second question, but for the first one you can use the focus() method.
like

```
x.focus();
```